# What does it mean if someone says "this experiment has a X distribution"?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Kindly, help me to clear my understanding of probability distribution.

As far as I understand, probability-distribution means a table/list which lists the probabilities of each outcome of an experiment.

But, What does it mean if someone says "this experiment has a X distribution"?

Suppose, I say, **hypothetically**, "A die roll experiment has a **normal** distribution". What would that mean?

If I want to see this myself using [this online calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573188), how can I do that? I mean, setting what values to which parameters would be able to give me a normal distribution for a die roll experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "X" must be substituted then for words like "normal, uniform, geometric, poisson..." i.e. labels that make clear what kind of distribution we are dealing with. If it concerns the roll of a fair six-sided die then the word "uniform" is correct and making it more precise it should be added that the distribution is  "discrete and on set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$".

A calculator that gives you normal distribution can only be used in this context if you are planning to look at averages of multiple die rolls.

Every normal distribution is determined by mean and variance, so these parameters must be calculated, and in case of die rolls you must work with $\mu=3.5$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{35}{12}$.

I don't think there is much to gain with that.

---

> "A die roll experiment has a normal distribution". What would that mean?

It means that - if random variable X is the result of a die roll - this random variable X has normal distribution (which is of course not true).